# How to use CSS to specified a div tag in my page

Tags: css

I have a html page like this. I want to know is if it is possible for me to apply this style 'bottom: 5.0rem' ONLY to the div tag of the parent of  below, but not to the div tag of the parent of the p? And I wan to know if i can do that without putting 'style=bottom: 5.0rem;' as the attribute of the

```
<div class="section">
    <a href="..."> 
           <div id="first"> 
                <img/>
                <div>  <--- but not here
                    <p>  some text </p>
                </div/
            </div>
     </a> 
     <div id="first">
             <div>   <---- only to here
                <a> anchor </a>
             <div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
.section div#first {
  bottom: 5.0rem;
}
```

But that apply the changes to both DIV tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific scenario, you can use the direct descendant selector

CSS

```
.section > div#first div {
    bottom: 5.0rem;
}
```

SASS

```
.section {
    > div#first {
        div {
           bottom: 5.0rem;
        }
    }
}
```

This means the div inside the anchor will not be targeted because it is not a direct descendant of the section.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, IDs should be **unique** on a page. If you need to have multiple, use a class. Once you've done that, you can simply do

```
.section > .first > div {}
```

Or nest using ampersand

```
.section {
    & > .first {
        & > div {}
    }
}
```